# How to write animation or activity transition on android TV as shown in figma file?

Tags: android-tv, google-tv, television

I am trying to create a android TV app and while coding, how to add those transition shown in figma in android TV? Everything is custom code and not used any leanback or any other.

In figma, designer has added : on click -> smart animate -> gentle. Now how to add this transition on android TV code?

I don't know how to try but I am expecting the same animation shown in figma in android TV app when user interacts.